# How to test a function that does a callout from another function?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, aura-enabled

In the code below, I'm calling GetBusinessDetails, which does a callout, from another function.  The problem is, the lines with the asterisks are not getting hit when I run a test and that lowers the code coverage. How can I get those lines to be hit as well? I'm already testing GetBusinessDetails individually by doing a mock call, but how can  I test it getting called from another method?

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable =true)
public static String GetUEIPhysicalAddressData(String uei) {
    try {
        BusinessInfoService.BusinessDetailsParam param = new BusinessInfoService.BusinessDetailsParam(uei);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = GetBusinessDetails(param);
      **strResponse = httpResponse.getBody();
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() != 200 ) {
            throw new CalloutException(strResponse);
        }**
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;  
    }
    ....
}
```

```java
public static HttpResponse GetBusinessDetails(BusinessInfoService.BusinessDetailsParam param){
    .....
    //  Instantiate a new Http object
    Http h = new Http();
                
    // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(fullEndpoint);
                      
        // Send the request, and return a response
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        return res;
    }
}
```

```java
@isTest
static void testGetUEIPhysicalAddressData() {
    string strUEI = 'ABFT6546';
    try {
        // get data
        string strData = BusinessInfoService.GetUEIPhysicalAddressData(strUEI);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //  Verify exception was thrown
        System.assert(ex.getMessage().length() > 0);
    }
}
        
@isTest
static void testGetCallout(){
    BusinessInfoService.BusinessDetailsParam ueiParam = new BusinessInfoService.BusinessDetailsParam('DGJRMMPNKCM1');
    // Create the mock response based on a static resource
    StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();            
    mock.setStaticResource('GetData');
    mock.setStatusCode(200);
    mock.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                
    // Associate the callout with a mock response
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
                
    // Call method to test
    HttpResponse result = BusinessInfoService.GetBusinessDetails(ueiParam);
                
    //  Verify mock response is not null
    System.assertNotEquals(null, result, 'The callout returned a null response.');
                
    //  Verify status code
    System.assertEquals(200, result.getStatusCode(), 'The status code is not 200.');
                
    //  Verify content type
    //System.assertEquals('text/plain;charset=UTF-8', result.getHeader('Content-Type'), 'The content type value is not expected.');
                
    // verify the array contains 4 items
    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)
                    JSON.deserializeUntyped(result.getBody());
        
    List<Object> bizInfo = (List<Object>) results.get('entityData');
        
    System.assertEquals(4, bizInfo.size(), 'The array should only contain 4 items.');
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see more of your code (i.e. the code for `GetBusinessDetails()` and the method it's calling to perform the actual callout) as well as the test class that you've written so far.

Comment: Burak, not sure, if I understand you fully, but you can use the same `Test.setMock()` (that you use testing your method doing the callout) before you call `GetUEIPhysicalAddressData()` from your unit test. In addition to that, you are always free to refactor everything below your `GetBusinessDetails()` call to be in a separate method, which you then call from inside your try - resp. from an additional test method.

Comment: I updated the code @DerekF and Felix van Hove